# Javascript - Get array length from multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can you get the length of this kind of array using javascript or jquery?

```
var Accounts = {
'Account001' : { 'data1' : 'foo1', 'data2' : 'bar1' },
'Account002' : { 'data1' : 'foo2', 'data2' : 'bar2' },
'Account003' : { 'data1' : 'foo3', 'data2' : 'bar3' },
'Account004' : { 'data1' : 'foo4', 'data2' : 'bar4' }
};
```

I tried Accounts.length but it seems to return NAN.

Comment: What you have is an object of objects and **not** an array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object
As mentioned by @KarelG its an object, not an array.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Object.keys(Accounts).length
```

You are trying to get the "length" of an object, which does not exist. If this were an array, it would be enclosed in a bracket [].

This is definitely an object, so in order to count the properties inside an object, you would have to use Object.keys() to contain the property names in an array and then count the elements from there.

Comment: Thanks this seems like the best solution for what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop to iterate over all the elements in the object and a count to get the number:

```js
var Accounts = {
'Account001' : { 'data1' : 'foo1', 'data2' : 'bar1' },
'Account002' : { 'data1' : 'foo2', 'data2' : 'bar2' },
'Account003' : { 'data1' : 'foo3', 'data2' : 'bar3' },
'Account004' : { 'data1' : 'foo4', 'data2' : 'bar4' }
};

var count = 0;
for(var k in Accounts) {
  if(Accounts.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```